# Binding to a property defined in the parent user control's code-behind from the control template of child custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a parent UserControl (`ParentUserControl`) which consists of a child CustomControl (`ChildCustomControl`). In the control template of my child custom control, I would like to bind to a property defined in the code-behind file, ParentUserControl.xaml.cs. If it is possible to do so, what would be the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine with `TemplateBinding`  ... e.g. `{TemplateBinding propName}`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily refer parent control using its Name. Xaml in this case will look like this:

```
<ParentUserControl Name="ParentControl">
  <ChildUserControl>
    <ChildUserControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ChildUserControl}">
        <Grid Background={Binding Path=Background, ElementName=ParentControl}>
...
```

Comment: ControlTemplate is usually defined in Generic.xaml and not alongwith custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bind a property in chid control's control template with the property of parent control using following binding:

```
PropertyName = "{Binding 
        Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType=ParentUserControl},
    Path=ParentPropertyName}"
```

Here `PropertyName` will be the property in child control's control template, `ParentUserControl` will be you parent user control name and the `ParentPropertyName` will be the property of parent control.

Comment: Did you check the output window for any binding errors? I have done the above to accomplish what you are trying to do with success in the past. Also could you provide the xaml you are using?